# Zoom to feature in WMS layer - openlayer 6

Tags: openlayers, javascript, web-gis

I know there are many similar questions but I can't find the answer to my problem. I want zoom to feature in my layer when click but I don't know why my code not working.

This my layer:

```
var view = new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: [11875495.42643146,1212033.3298334656],
    });
    var source = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/vietnam/wms',
        params: {LAYERS: 'mycountry:mylayer', 'TILED': true},
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        ratio: 1,
    });
     myLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        view: view,
        source: source,
        visible: true,
        title: 'myLayerMap',
    });
    map.addLayer(myLayer);
```

This my code:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click
});
var feature = myLayer.getFeatures();
map.addInteraction(select);
select.on('select', function () {
    var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
    mapView.fit(extent, map.getSize());
    console.log(extent);
})
```

I'm try with `console.log(extent);` but nothing to show in  browser console log. Where did I wrong?

Update:
I try another option:

```
var features = myLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
var myFeature = features[0];
var ext = myFeature.getGeometry().getExtent();
var center = ol.extent.getCenter(ext);
map.setView( new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    center: [center[0] , center[1]],
    zoom: 14
}));
```

and an error appeared `myLayer.getSource(...).getFeatures is not a function` though I did the same before

I do it with suggestion of @TomazicM but it do not work and nothing show in browser console log

```
        map.on('click', function (evt) {
        var viewResolution = mapView.getResolution();
        var url = source.getFeatureInfoUrl(
          evt.coordinate,
          viewResolution,
          'EPSG:4326',
          {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'},
        );
        if (url) {
            fetch(url, function(data){
                var feature = data.features[0];
                // var props = feature.properties;
                var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent()
                view.fit(extent, map.getSize(),{duration:250})
                console.log(extent);
            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved my problem as suggested by previous comments...

```
var parser = new ol.format.WMSGetFeatureInfo();
map.on('click', function(evt) {
var view = map.getView();
var url = myLayer.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate,
    view.getResolution(),
    view.getProjection(),
    {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/vnd.ogc.gml'}
);
$.ajax(url).then(function(response) {
    var features = parser.readFeatures(response);
    var extent = features[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
    // console.log(extent);
    view.fit(extent,{duration:350})
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to query the features from a WMS image, rather than the features of a Vector layer. If it's possible, I would recommend using a WFS for this specific task, even if its styled to be invisible on the map.

If this isn't possible, you should look into GetFeatureInfo on Geoserver which you can find an example of
[here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html)

Comment: I'm tried with this but I don't know how to do that, I'm newbie. Please help me, I'm stuck

Comment: Where is your WMS getting its data from? I assume from a database/ shapefile/ geopackage?

Comment: sorry for delay, I import my shapefile to PostgreSQL, then public them in Geoserver and show layer on map with WMS image